# ANN Perceptron OR-Gate training does not work correctly

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

So I am trying to train an OR-gate with basically a Perceptron. The problem is that it does not work. The wrong one is 0 0 -> desired = 0, actual = 1. And that one doesn't change.

Furthermore, when I put the weights that I got to test, they don't seem to work at all either, but this could be something that is wrong with my testOut function.

```
public class Temp {

double[][] data = {{0.d, 0.d}, {0.d, 1.d}, {1.d, 0.d}, {1.d, 1.d}};
double[] outputs = {0.d, 1.d, 1.d, 1.d};
double[][] weights = {
        {ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5),
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5)},
        {ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5),
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5)},
        {ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5),
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5)},
        {ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5),
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-.5, .5)}
};

public double[][] train(int maxEpoch, double threshhold) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxEpoch; i++) {
        System.out.println("EPOCH " + i);
        double sum = 0.0d;
        double actualOutput = 0.0d;
        double[] ep = new double[outputs.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < data[j].length; k++) {
                sum += data[j][k] * weights[j][k];
            }
            actualOutput = step(sum - threshhold);
            ep[j] = outputs[j] - actualOutput;
            for (int k = 0; k < data[j].length; k++) {
                weights[j][k] = weights[j][k] + .1 * data[j][k] * ep[j];
            }
            System.out.println("output " + j + " " + actualOutput + " " + outputs[j] +" - " + ep[j]);
        }
    }
    return weights;

}

public void testOut(double[][] data, double[][] weights, double threshhold){
    double sum = 0;
    double[] actualOutput = new double[data.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < data[j].length; k++) {
            sum += data[j][k] * weights[j][k];
        }
        actualOutput[j] = step(sum - threshhold);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(actualOutput));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temp t = new Temp();
    double[][] weights = t.train(200, 0);
    t.testOut(t.data, weights, .5);
}
}
```

Any Help appreciated.

Edit: step(sum - threshold) is the step function.

```
public static int step(double x) {
        return x >= 0.d ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide steps() method definition??

Comment: public static int step(double x) {
  return x >= 0.d ? 1 : 0;
 }

Comment: O/p is something like : EPOCH 0..........., EPOCH 1........,----EPOCH 199. Then where r u getting the problem?? What exactly u want??

Comment: Basically I put data in x1, x2 values, and the outputs should represent an OR gate, so 0 0 -> 0, 0 1 -> 1, etc... Problem is that it doesn't converge (with 200 epochs, which is a lot. should actually converge in ~5). So I keep getting 0 0 -> 1, which is an error and shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

So I kinda solved the problem. The step function gave back 0, because of the value of the threshold. I made it .2d instead and now it works fine.